# Get max date based on the URL string having multiple records

Tags: sql, url, group-by, max

This is my data, where I need to get last access date of every unique URL.

DATA

```
AccessDate  URL
20220523    /sites/brazil/sitepages/home.aspx
20220518    /sites/brazil/sitepages/home.aspx
20220621    /sites/turkey/blog.aspx
20220224    /sites/turkey/dashboards.aspx
20220623    /sites/brazil/sitepages/about.aspx
20210629    /sites/usa/service.aspx
20210728    /sites/usa/winodws.aspx
20211117    /sites/turkey/new.aspx
20220513    /sites/brazil/sitepages/home.aspx
```

There is huge data. I will provide the set of URLs whose last access date I want to get.

INPUT- may in WHERE clause

```
/sites/brazil/
/sites/usa/
/sites/turkey/
```

OUTPUT

```
AccessDate  URL
20220623    /sites/brazil/
20210728    /sites/usa/
20220621    /sites/turkey/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution with *SQL Server*

```
select   max(AccessDate)                   as AccessDate
        ,left(url, charindex('/', url, 8)) as url
from     t
group by left(url, charindex('/', url, 8))
```

| AccessDate | url |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-06-23 00:00:00.000 | /sites/brazil/ |
| 2022-06-21 00:00:00.000 | /sites/turkey/ |
| 2021-07-28 00:00:00.000 | /sites/usa/ |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/TYhcGjkz?hide=4)

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT
CASE 
WHEN URL LIKE '/sites/brazil/%' THEN '/sites/brazil/'
WHEN URL LIKE '/sites/usa%' THEN '/sites/usa/'
WHEN URL LIKE '/sites/turkey%' THEN '/sites/turkey/'
END AS URL
, MAX(AccessDate) AS AcessDate
FROM 
table
GROUP BY
1
```

Comment: It's not working actually. We have to do group by on part of URL string. Here you did on date.

Comment: I think you need to explain your question a bit better... I did what I understood you asked :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with *Postgres*

```
select   max(accessdate)                                        as AccessDate
        ,array_to_string((string_to_array(url, '/'))[1:3], '/') as url       
from     t
group by array_to_string((string_to_array(url, '/'))[1:3], '/')
```

| accessdate | url |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-06-23 | /sites/brazil |
| 2022-06-21 | /sites/turkey |
| 2021-07-28 | /sites/usa |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/khXU2aaw?hide=8)

Comment: My database is MS SQL and I am using SQL Management Studio. How to achive this in MS SQL?

Comment: @SBP I posted another solution. See if it works for you.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT 
MAX(AccessDate) AS S_AccessDate, LEFT(URL, LEN('/sites/brazil/')) AS S_URL
FROM Table
WHERE URL LIKE '/sites/brazil/%'
GROUP BY LEFT(URL, LEN('/sites/brazil/'))
```

Comment: What about turkey, usa?